# Weak version Fatou lemma

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I want to show the weak version Fatou Lemma; i.e.,

---

Let $f \ge 0$ be continuous function. If $X_n \rightarrow X$ in distribution, then 
$$
\liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty} E f(X_n) \ge Ef(X)
$$

---

Here is my thought:
I know that if $X_n \rightarrow X$ in distribution, then there exists another random variables $Y_n$ and $Y$ such that the distribution $F_{X_n} = F_{Y_n}$ and $F_X = F_Y$ and $Y_n \rightarrow Y$ almost surely. (1)

and since the original Fatou Lemma says that: 
If $Y_n \rightarrow Y$ almost surely, and if $f \ge 0$ then we have
$$
\liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty} E f(Y_n) \ge Ef(Y)
$$

So I combine (1) and original Fatou Lemma, then get
 $$
\liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty} E f(Y_n) \ge Ef(Y)
$$

But I stuck on how to take advantage of using that fact that $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are the same distribution to infer that 
 $$
\liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty} E f(X_n) \ge Ef(X)
$$
I think the question in my mind is that if $X_n$ and $Y_n$ has the same distribution, then what can I say about its expectation? e.g., Is this legal to saying that $EX_n = EY_n ?$

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for reply, @brom ,  but I still quite confused about how the integral $E[X] = \int_\Omega XdP =?= \int_R P(X \ge t) dt$. Could you please say more words about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is true that $EX_n = EY_n$ since, if $X_n, Y_n \geq 0$ as is the case here, we have
$$EX = \int_0^\infty \! P(X \geq t)\, dt$$
and this last term depends only on the distribution. The argument proving this is essentially

$$EX = \int_\Omega \! X(\omega) \, dP(\omega)$$
$$= \int_\Omega \! \int_{0}^{X(\omega)} 1 \, dt \, dP(\omega)$$
$$= \int_\Omega \! \int_{0}^{\infty} 1_{\{t \le X(\omega)\}} \, dt \, dP(\omega)$$ 
$$= \int_0^\infty\! \int_\Omega \! 1_{\{t \le X(\omega)\}} \, dP(\omega)\, dt$$
$$ = \int_0^\infty \! P(X \geq t) \, dt.$$

Here we used Tonelli's theorem in the second to last inequality.

Comment: Thank you so much! @brom .

Comment: @Fianra There were some problems with the answer before. After some wild editing, I think I have managed to save the situation :)

Comment: @user38355 How can you justify to exchange the integrals ?