# Convergence of expectations of random variables

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

> Let $Y_n, n \in \mathbb{N}$ be a sequence of non-negative random variables on $L_1(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ such that
>
> 1. $\mathbb{E}Y_n = 1$ and $\mathbb{E}(Y_n \,\ln Y_n) \leq 1$, $\forall n\in \mathbb N$
> 2. $\mathbb{E}(Y_n \,Z) \rightarrow \mathbb{E}(Y Z) $ for all bounded random variables $Z$ on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$
>
> How do I prove that $Y\geq 0$ a.s., $\mathbb{E}Y = 1 $ and $\mathbb{E}(Y \ln Y) \leq 1$?

I was thinking that maybe I should first prove that $Y_n \rightarrow Y$ a.s.
which should somehow follow from (2.) and than apply convergence theorems.

Comment: Don't you need Y_n,Y strictly greater than zero to take the ln?

Comment: Maybe we can assume that  $Y_n, Y$ take values in the extended real line

Comment: Yes, if course. By the way, I am not happy with some implications in my answer, so I am reconsidering it.

Answer (score 2):

The random variable $Z(ω)=\mathbf 1_{\{ω\in Ω\}}(ω)$ or equivalentlty $Z\equiv 1$, is bounded. Hence, by (2.) $$\mathbb E(Y)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb E(Y_n)\overset{(1.)}=\lim_{n\to\infty}1=1$$ Moreover, since for any $A \in \mathcal F$ the function $Z_A=\mathbf 1_{\{ω\in A\}}$ is bounded, you have by (2.) and the [Portmanteu lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Properties) that $Y_n\to Y$ in distribution. The [continuous mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_mapping_theorem), implies that also $g(Y_n):=Y_n\ln Y_n\to g(Y):=Y\ln Y$ in distribution. 
Since, $P(Y_n<0)=0$ for any $n\in\mathbb N$, convergence in distribution implies that $$0=\lim_{n\to\infty}P(Y_n<0)=P(Y<0)$$ hence $Y\ge 0$ a.s. It remains to show that $\mathbb E(Y\ln{Y})\le 1$.

Comment: $x <  \ln(x)$ for any $x > 0$? What about $x =1$?

Comment: "Since $\mathbb{E}(Y_n) = 1$, you know that the $Y_n's$ are a.s. bounded". What about letting $X_n= U(0,1)$ (uniform distribution on (0,1)) and taking $Y_n = -\ln(X_n)$?

Comment: @user159517 If I am correct, in your example $Y_n \sim \exp(1)$ and hence $\mathbb E(Y_n)=1$ but the $Y_n$'s are unbounded, right?

Comment: That's what I'm saying, yes.

Comment: @user159517 Ok, I see the problem in my reasoning. Hmmm, let me think how I can correct it. Thanks a lot for the feedback.

Comment: How can you say that $Y_n \ln Y_n$ is non-negative and that $\liminf Y_n \ln Y_n = Y \log Y$ in order to apply Fatou's lemma?

Comment: For the second part, this is not a problem by Skorohod's theorem, see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/959790/weak-version-fatou-lemma) for example. But for the first part you are right, $Y_n\ln Y_n$ needs not to be positive, which is not necessarily the case/

Comment: @Jules Now I have doubts about portmanteau as well...